# Build Multiple jars from a Maven Project

Tags: java, maven

I'm fighting against the single artifact rule of Maven. I have a complex project with 100s of xsds and wsdls. I want to use the xjc plugin to generate java sources from the xsds, compile them and package them into independent jars.

Similarly I'm trying to generate independent jars from the classes generated out of the wsdl using the jaxws-maven-plugin.

Dividing the project into 100 sub-projects will make it too complex and will make it very difficult to maintain.

I need a single jar per xsd, and a single jar per wsdl.

Is there a way around this? a custom plugin maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom Maven Plugin which uses https://github.com/TimMoore/mojo-executor to handle the package install and deploy phases.

To generate separate sources for each xsd or wsdl int separate directories, I wrote another Mojo which will generate the sources using JAVA_HOME\bin executables xjc and wsimport

To generate separate jars out of these sources, I invoked the maven-compiler-plugin and maven-jar-plugin using mojo-executor

and finally to do the install and deploy bits, invoked the maven-install-plugin and maven-deploy-plugin using mojo-executor

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider a [multi module maven project](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html).
You can still keep all your files in a single project, just divide them between all the project sub modules.
This might seem too much trouble, but you will enjoy the maven conventions and capabilities.

Keep it simple. Even if it seems more work.

I hope this helps.